# Know if a video Youtube is unavailable with the API

Tags: youtube-api

Via the Youtube API, how can I detect if a video Youtube is unavailable (ex : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5nRZlcB2jPY) ?

Thanks

Comment: welcome to stack please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If a video is not available it will return 403 error code...you can do a callback if the response is error free

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would make an API call for the video status.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=VIDEOID&part=status&key=APIKEY
```

Then check the [uploadStatus](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#status.uploadStatus) in the json result:

```
"status": {
"uploadStatus": "processed",
"privacyStatus": "public",
"license": "youtube",
"embeddable": true,
"publicStatsViewable": true
}
```

Comment: Great ! That's it ! Thanks

Comment: Well the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6k4108PYgOk is not available on YouTube but the YouTube API reports the following status for the video:`"status": {
    "uploadStatus": "processed",
    "privacyStatus": "public",
    "license": "youtube",
    "embeddable": true,
    "publicStatsViewable": true
   }`. What should be the correct status for an available video ?

Comment: It's unavailable on YouTube for your region. Check region restrictions too: https://unblockvideos.com/youtube-video-restriction-checker/#url=6k4108PYgOk

Comment: Vincent, video 8EzdmE4Ewqk is fine, and don't hijack someone's thread.

Comment: @johnh10 comments useful for me. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 2):

This is also partially possible *without* API. Let's say you want to see if the following video is available:

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=esDJPiGu5x0

The ID of the video is shown as the GET parameter `v`. Use this one to request the following thumbnail:

> https://img.youtube.com/vi/esDJPiGu5x0/0.jpg

If the content of the response has a length of *0* and/or the http response code by youtube.com is `404`, then the video is not available anymore.

Comment: Can't confirm. It just worked for me. Perhaps the preview images were not generated yet?

Comment: If image doesn't exist, then video doesn't exist. But if the image exists, it is no guarantee that the video is available

Answer (score 1):

You can check it without API.

```
const https = require('https');

// Change your videoId that you want to check here
const url = 'https://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=videoID&format=json';

https.get(url, (response) => {
  if (response.statusCode === 200) {
    console.log('Video available');
  } else {
    console.log('Video not available');
  }
}).on('error', (error) => {
  console.error('Error:', error);
});
```

If you get a response of 200, the video is available. If not, the video is unavailable